# Is there a built-in function which can send a send signal to AUX hardware?

Tags: javascript, browser, mobile-browser

I am not trying to play a music, but am connecting a hardware to AUX jack and it needs a number to operate. As per my knowledge browser's (implementation of) JS provides many built-in utilities. Are there any function calls which can satisfy my needs? Can it be used in mobile devices (may/not be a smartphone)?

Comment: No, web pages have a very limited access outside of the browser

Comment: Some mobiles use [Kai OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KaiOS) and it's built-on top of Firefox OS.
OS can control hardware right? Then doesn't browser provide some apis for this?
I saw something called [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) and an [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode)
I guess any examples on this lines would help solve my problem.

Comment: webrtc api has noting to do with "aux jack" level of accessibility